# .htaccess rewrite specific page with backslash parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Please helt - I need a rewriteRule for a specific page with backslash paramters like:

```
/page/parameter1/paramter2
```

Rewriterule to

```
/anotherpage/paramter1/paramter2
```

tried this but i did not work:

```
RewriteRule ^page/$ /anotherpage.php/$ [L]
```

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /anotherpage/$1 [L,NC]`

Comment: Thanks a lot Anybhava !!!! - it worked  - you are a life saver :D ....  how do I accept you answer... (sorry Im new to this forum)

Comment: You cannot accept a comment only answer can be accepted by marking a tick mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this rule:

```bash
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /anotherpage/$1 [L,NC]
```

Note that we match any text after `page/` into a capture group and use the back-reference of the capture group `$1` in the target.